# Не удаляются и не добавляются классы

Tags: javascript, html

Коллеги, добрый день. Написал простенькую схему, при клике на ссылку должно выводиться на экран сообщение, но я кликаю на ссылку - ничего не происходит. Так же прописал ссылке отмену перехода по ссылке при нажатии на неё, пробовал это убирать - не работает всё равно, что я делаю не так?

```js
$(".green__left-top-title").click((event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
});
const greenLink = document.querySelectorAll('.green__left-top-title');

greenLink.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

  alert('Test');

});
```

```html
<div class="green__left-top">
  <a href="#green-1" class="green__left-top-title">продажа</a>
  <a href="#green-2" class="green__left-top-title">закрепление</a>
  <a href="#green-3" class="green__left-top-title">ограничения</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `greenLink` это целая коллекция элементов. С ней нельзя работать как с одним элементом.

Comment: А как работать? Я же пишу greenLink[i]

Comment: @Андрей в коде вы не пишете greenLink[i]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` возвращает коллекцию элементов. Их нужно перебрать в цикле, допустим через метод forEach(). То есть на каждый элемент вешаем слушатель.

```js
const greenLink = document.querySelectorAll('.green__left-top-title');

greenLink.forEach(el => {  
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(el.href);
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="green__left-top">
  <a href="#green-1" class="green__left-top-title">продажа</a>
  <a href="#green-2" class="green__left-top-title">закрепление</a>
  <a href="#green-3" class="green__left-top-title">ограничения</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы мне глаза открыли, что он возвращает коллекцию)

Comment: @Андрей а разве об этом в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) не сказано? Ну или чисто логически когда написано `**ALL** не наталкивает на мысли?))

Answer (score 3):

> не работает всё равно, что я делаю не так?

Используй делегирование событий. Таким образом ты обойдешься одним обработчиком на все однотипные элементы…

```js
$(".green__left-top").click(event => {
  const o = event.target
  if (o.tagName != 'A') return
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(o.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="green__left-top">
  <a href="#green-1" class="green__left-top-title">продажа</a>
  <a href="#green-2" class="green__left-top-title">закрепление</a>
  <a href="#green-3" class="green__left-top-title">ограничения</a>
</div>
```

Вариант на чистом JS будет не особо отличаться...

```js
document.querySelector(".green__left-top").addEventListener('click', event => {
  const o = event.target
  if (o.tagName != 'A') return
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(o.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div class="green__left-top">
  <a href="#green-1" class="green__left-top-title">продажа</a>
  <a href="#green-2" class="green__left-top-title">закрепление</a>
  <a href="#green-3" class="green__left-top-title">ограничения</a>
</div>
```

Добавил еще вариант с другим методом jQuery...

```js
$(".green__left-top").on('click', 'a', e => {
  const o = e.target
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(o.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="green__left-top">
  <a href="#green-1" class="green__left-top-title">продажа</a>
  <a href="#green-2" class="green__left-top-title">закрепление</a>
  <a href="#green-3" class="green__left-top-title">ограничения</a>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно пример на чистом JS пожалуйста?

Comment: в метках нет jquery....

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, добавил

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, зато в примере ТСа `jquery` присутствует.

Comment: кстати на jquery для делегирования есть специальный синтаксис. который позволит избежать такого ненужного кода

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в данном случае и этот синтаксис будет рабочий...

Comment: Рабочий да, использование больше кода - намного бессмысленней.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, добавил и смысла... :)